Saving cross-origin browser cookie
I have a MERN app with client and server parts hosted on different urls. I need to set a session cookie on the browser. During local testing, the following setup works fine:
app.use(
    "/user",
    session({
        secret: sessionSecret,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false,
            sameSite: 'lax'
        },
        store: MongoStore.create({
            mongoUrl: url,
        })
    })
);

However in production environment, the cookie is returned by server, but not set in the browser. The following warning is visible in browser : "this attempt to set a cookie was blocked because samesite=lax ... "
I tweaked the code for production environment as
app.use(
    "/user",
    session({
        secret: sessionSecret,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            secure: node_env == "PROD" ? true : false,
            sameSite: node_env == "PROD" ? 'none' : 'lax',
            partitioned: node_env == "PROD" ? true : false,
        },
        store: MongoStore.create({
            mongoUrl: url,
        })
    })
);

Now even the cookie is not returned to the browser. I tried using partitioned: true but the issue persists.

Partitioned cookies must also have sameSite: "none" and secure: true. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79301404/session-cookie-not-being-set-in-browser
