Chrome blocking ads on site without ad
I have a MERN web app with frontend and backend deployed on different services and urls. I am using cookies for session management.
However chrome is displaying the warning in console:

Chrome is blocking ads on this site because this site tends to show ads that interrupt, distract, mislead, or prevent user control. You should fix the issues as soon as possible and submit your site for another review.

However there are no ads on my site. Moreover, the session cookies I am trying to set are not getting stored on the browser.
While I am not sure, I guess that chrome has mistaken this behavior of my app with third party ad cookies and blocked them. The error message is not very helpful. And while the message says to send the site for review, it does not mention where to.

https://support.google.com/webtools/answer/7305902

If your session cookies are blocked as third-party, consider partitioning them, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79301404/session-cookie-not-being-set-in-browser
