Why is my cookie being deleted automatically?
The cookies are being sent to the front-end and are arriving correctly, but after a page reload, they are deleted. The backend is built with Node and is hosted on a VM separate from where the front-end with React is hosted, all on Hostinger. I have everything configured correctly, and the only thing that is failing is this. I am using Axios and it is configured like this:
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { logOutRequest } from "../api/auth"; // En caso de que necesites hacer logout
import { API_URL } from "../config";

// Crear la instancia de axios
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL, // Asegúrate de definir tu URL base en un archivo de configuración
  withCredentials: true,
});

// Interceptor de solicitud (request)
instance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = Cookies.get("token"); // Obtener el token de las cookies
    console.log("SOY EL TOKEN: " + token);
    
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`; // Añadir el token a los headers si está presente
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

// Interceptor de respuesta (response)
instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response; // Retornar respuesta si es exitosa
  },
  async (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true; // Evitar bucles infinitos de reintento

      try {
        // Intentar renovar el token
        const refreshTokenResponse = await axios.post(
          `${API_URL}/usuarios/refresh`,
          {},
          { withCredentials: true }
        );

        if (refreshTokenResponse.status === 200 || refreshTokenResponse.status === 304) {
          const newAccessToken = refreshTokenResponse.data; // Obtener nuevo access token
          Cookies.set("token", newAccessToken, {
            secure: true,
            sameSite: "none",
          });

          // Reintentar la solicitud original con el nuevo token
          originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`;
          return axios(originalRequest);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        await logOutRequest(); // Cerrar sesión en caso de error
        window.location.href = "/login"; // Redirigir al usuario a la página de login
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default instance;

and that is my endpoint in login:
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const userFound = await Usuario.findOne({ where: { email } });

    if (!userFound)
      return res.status(400).json({
        ok: false,
        message: "El email o la contraseña son incorrectos.",
      });

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, userFound.password);
    if (!isMatch) {
      console.log("yo");
      return res.status(400).json({
        ok: false,
        message: "El email o la contraseña son incorrectos.",
      });
    }

    const refreshToken = await createRefreshToken({
      id: userFound.id,
      username: userFound.nombre,
      email: userFound.email,
    });

    res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      domain:"donorione.edu.ar",
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 
    });

    const token = await createAccessToken({
      id: userFound.id,
      username: userFound.nombre,
      email: userFound.email,
    });

    res.cookie("token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      domain:"donorione.edu.ar",

      maxAge: 20 * 60 * 1000
    });

    res.json(token);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};


If frontend and backend are on different sites, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79301404/session-cookie-not-being-set-in-browser
